# What size are the pipe fittings on the feed line side of a sink feed?

Tags: pipe, sink, fitting

Trying to figure out what size the feed lines ( and the dish washer T ) are under my kitchen sink. I measured the OD of the metal mesh and it looks around 1.2 inch, but I'm not sure if these are standard.

[image]

Comment: Dishwashers and kitchen sinks are usually 3/8" or 1/2" fittings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a standard [braided supply line](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BrassCraft-3-8-in-Compression-x-1-2-in-FIP-x-36-in-Braided-Polymer-Faucet-Connector-B1-36A-F/205214581?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-VF-PLA-D26P-Plumbing%7C&gclid=CjwKEAjwzN27BRDFn9aAwLmH2yISJABWuEXciXA9a_GQqW97TbluzMTMJNUApv_VYon_H49nNEC-dRoCEL_w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). available at practically any hardware store in various lengths